# How to apply to the parameters that I have to create a plug-in plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

```
 (function( $ ){
        var methods = {
            init : function( options ) {
                var settings = $.extend({      //Объявление настроек по умолчанию, которые можно переопределить в вызове плагина
                    code: 7,
                    listHeight: 160,
                    placeholder: "925000000",
                    phoneNumber: ""
                }, options);
            },
            getCode : function( ) {
                return $(this).settings.code;
            }
        };
        $.fn.telephoneNumber = function( method ) {
            if ( methods[method] ) {
                return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
            } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
                return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
            } else {
                $.error( 'Метод с именем ' +  method + ' не существует.' );
            }
        };
    })( jQuery );
```

I need to refer to a variable **code** from a function **getCode**.

**Function getCode returns nothing, how fix?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `this` in the call to your plugin will refer to the jQuery instance on which it was called, you can't use it to refer directly to your plugin's information.

The usual way to handle this is to store any information your plugin needs using jQuery's [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data) function. Here's a simple example (this is loosely based in your code, but not an exact update of it; it's just an example):

```
(function ($) {
    var methods = {
        init: function (options) {
            // Save settings using `data`
            this.data("myplugin", $.extend({/*...*/}, options));
        },
        doSomething: function () {
            // Get settings using `data`
            var settings = this.data("myplugin");
            // Use them...
        }
    };
    var slice = Array.prototype.slice;
    $.fn.myplugin = function (command) {
        if (typeof command === "string") {
            methods[command].apply(this, slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else {
            methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        }
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ETiRUde/1)

Note that your code requires that the user call the plugin to initialize it, and then again to call a method on it, which I've reproduced above. So:

```
$("some selector").myplugin();              // Init
$("some selector").myplugin("doSomething"); // Use
```

You could auto-init with defaults if the user doesn't do that, by changing the plugin function like this:

```
$.fn.myplugin = function (command) {
    if (typeof command === "string") {
        if (!this.data("myplugin")) { // Not initialized?
            methods.init.call(this);  // Init with defaults
        }
        methods[command].apply(this, slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else {
        methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    return this;
};
```

[Here's that in action](http://jsbin.com/ETiRUde/2)

Comment: thanks, but console.log(settings.code); - no output to the console in getCode

Comment: @user3274299: The above (other than a missing `)`, which I've added) works correctly. See the live example I've added.

Comment: @user3274299 I assume you know that based on your logic you NEED to call `init` before having default settings?

Answer (score -1):

`settings` has scope limited to `init` method as you've defined it there only. `getCode` function has no access to this variable.
Just define the `settings` globally, and you can access it in `getCode`.

Comment: var defaults = {
            code: 7,
            listHeight: 160,
            placeholder: "925000000",
            phoneNumber: ""
        }
        var methods = {
            init : function( options ) {How get options and assign them defaults?
            },

Comment: I don't understand negative feedback here. The defaults is totally available inside methods function though.

Comment: It is not I put a minus

Comment: DOesn't matter. Are you able to access the defaults now?

Comment: I can see a reason for the downvote: If you make `settings` global (or global to the plug-in), then you can have separate settings for individual instances of the plugin, which would seem to be important. That's why people use `data` or a closure (although there are issues with the closure approach).

Comment: Maybe then I wasn't clear. All I wanted to say is global to both functions `init` and `getCode`.